# jQuery scroll AFTER CSS Change

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, window

I built some modal windows that appear using CSS. However, they're showing up at the **top of the page**, rather than the **top of the window**. I would make things fixed, but sometimes the modal window is long and needs to be absolute so you can scroll through and read longer info in the modal box.

To remedy this I'd like to:

- either write some jQuery to scroll up to the top of the page,
- or find
  a way to make the modal appear at the top of the window (rather than
  the page).

Here's a JSFiddle for you to see what I'm working with:
https://jsfiddle.net/4f4qa1w5/4/

And the code if you'd like to see it here:

```js
$(".modal-container").css("display") == "block", function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300);
  return false;
};
```

```css
.modal-container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  display: none;
}
.modal-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
.modal:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.modal:target:before {
  display: block;
}
.modal:target .modal-container {
  top: 125px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<a href="#listen">
  <h2>Click to Listen</h2>
</a>
<div class="modal" id="listen">
  <div class="modal-container album-modal">
    <div class="close"><a class="red-it" href="#">X</a></div>
    <br>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was the markup had some unclosed `div`'s that were messing up my `class` and `id` selections.

Check out the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egzfa3x5/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick to solve your problem.

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#trigger").click(function(){
    $(".modal").css("display","block");
    $(".modal").css("overflow-y","auto");
    $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    $(".modal-container").css("display","block");
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");//
    return false;//
  })
})


$(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal").css("display","none");
    $(".modal").css("overflow-y","");
    $("body").css("overflow","");
    window.location.hash = $("#trigger").attr("id");
  })
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/717pnpwj/)

Comment: This is a really efficient solution, but it doesn't solve the problem. This works so long as the modal window isn't longer than the viewport. But my modal windows often have pop-ups that are longer than the window (add about 7 lorem p's for an example). How can I make it so I can still scroll them down?

Comment: @SamGranger i already add about 7 lorem . it still can  scroll them down. can u draw the layout? lol

Comment: This is a crude example of what I'm looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/8ccf8877/  (of course I wouldn't have that much info in a modal, but still...) Now that solution would work just fine, if only I could get the black background of .modal to cover everything. Any suggestions on that @Fiido93 ?

Comment: Check new demo, i already change the source code. @SamGranger

Comment: @SamGranger did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes! That solution does everything I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can this solution also work for multiple ids? If I have different modals that drop down based on different clicks (Clicking #listen1, #listen2, or #listen3 brings down three different windows)? See in this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egzfa3x5/

Comment: this is a different question, Of course it can't work with multiple id's

Answer (score 0):

This is only a potentially partial answer to a further question:

How do you use this solution (https://jsfiddle.net/717pnpwj/) with multiple ids?

See the multi id JS Fiddle: [ Link removed. See below ]

I know the below code doesn't work, but maybe it's closer to a multi-`id` solution:

```
 $(function(){
  $("[id$=-open]").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var targetId = id.replace('-open','');
    var $target = $('#' + targetId);
  $($target).css("display","block");
  $($target).css("overflow-y","auto");
  $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
  $($target > ".modal-container").css("display","block");
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  })
 })
```

NOTE: The problem was in the mark up. Check out the answer above and the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/egzfa3x5/4/